# Using for loop i R to create new columns based on columns created within the loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to simulate a ten year risk of dying for three populations with different proportions of treated patients. I already did this on a yearly basis for ten years, and it turned out to be a pretty long code. What I want is to convert this to a monthly basis for ten years, and to avoid hundreds of lines of code, I would like to use a for loop.

## my data looks like this

```
set.seed(1234)
N <- 750000

id <- c(1:N)

###creates a sex variable for men and appends women
treated <- rep.int(0,125000)
treated <- append(treated, rep.int(1,125000))
treated <- append(treated, rep.int(0,100000))
treated <- append(treated, rep.int(1,150000))
treated <- append(treated, rep.int(0,75000))
treated <- append(treated, rep.int(1,175000))

groupname <- rep.int(1,250000)
groupname <- c(groupname, rep.int(2,250000))
groupname <- c(groupname, rep.int(3,250000))
```

#### creates dataframe from sex and id vectors

```
data = data.frame(treated, id, groupname)
class(data$treated)
data$treated <- factor(data$treated, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("untreated","treated"))
data$groupname <- factor(data$groupname, levels = c(1,2,3), labels = c("group 1", "group 2", "group 3"))
```

then I generate each "wave", for the ten years like this (basicly the same code, just with a new column name assigned for each wave):

```
data$year_0 <- 1
data$year_1 <-  ifelse(data$treated=="treated",rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4), rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))

data$year_2 <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", 
                      ifelse(data$year_1 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4)), 
                      ifelse(data$year_1 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))
)
data$year_3 <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", 
                      ifelse(data$year_2 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4)), 
                      ifelse(data$year_2 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))
)
data$year_4 <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", 
                      ifelse(data$year_3 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4)), 
                      ifelse(data$year_3 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))
)
data$year_5 <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", 
                      ifelse(data$year_4 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4)), 
                      ifelse(data$year_4 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))
)
data$year_6 <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", 
                      ifelse(data$year_5 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4)), 
                      ifelse(data$year_5 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))
)
data$year_7 <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", 
                      ifelse(data$year_6 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4)), 
                      ifelse(data$year_6 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))
)
data$year_8 <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", 
                      ifelse(data$year_7 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4)), 
                      ifelse(data$year_7 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))
)
data$year_9 <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", 
                      ifelse(data$year_8 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4)), 
                      ifelse(data$year_8 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))
)
data$year_10 <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", 
                       ifelse(data$year_9 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4)), 
                       ifelse(data$year_9 =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))
)
###converts to long format
data_long <- reshape(data, direction="long", varying= c(list(4:14)), sep = "_", 
                     idvar="id", timevar=c("year"))
class(data_long$year)  
data_long$year <- as.numeric(data_long$year)
data_long$year <- data_long$year -1
```

I want to do this using a for loop, so I could simulate 120 months
I wrote this code

```
for (i in 1:10){ n <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", 
                                      ifelse(data$year_[(i-1)] =="0",  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4)), 
                                      ifelse(data$year_[(i-1)] =="0",  

0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))

                                 )
              data$year_[i] <- n 
    }

##1: I data$year_[i] <- n :

##error number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

as I understand, this error indicates that the way for loop is coded returns data of a length that are incompatible. Usually I can troubleshoot by google, but as the code runs when I'm not in the for loop
I don't understand where the problem is.
i Considered that the error may be be in the interpretation of the [i]not as a string that can be used for naming columns, but using paste just resulted in this warning in addition to the already mentioned one.

```
##Fejl i `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "year_", value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,  : 
  ##replacement has 750001 rows, data has 750000
```

and the google results on this issue doesn't really seem to state this as an issue.
So the problem is now, that I don't know enough to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Why you don't put the columns `year_i` in an extra matrix? Then you can use `cbind()` to extend the matrix column by column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the bracketed reference `[[...]]` to a column name to pass a string with `paste0()` and condition for first year and then all else years:

```
data$year_0 <- 1

for (i in 1:10){ 
  if (i == 1){
     n <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4), rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))
  } 
  else {
     n <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", 
                 ifelse(data[[paste0("year_", i-1)]] == 0,  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4)), 
                 ifelse(data[[paste0("year_", i-1)]] == 0,  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))
          )
  }
  data[[paste0("year_", i)]] <- n 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, it works like a charm. Just a shame that my computer cannot manage to reshape the data into long format because of the size. But thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Look into `reshape2` package's `melt` for long format.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the columns `year_i` in an extra matrix. Then you can use `cbind()` to extend the matrix column by column:

```
set.seed(1234)
N <- 750000

data = data.frame(treated=rep(c(0,1,0,1,0,1), c(125000, 125000, 100000, 150000, 75000, 175000)), id=1:N, 
groupname=rep(1:3, each=250000))
data$treated <- factor(data$treated, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("untreated","treated"))
data$groupname <- factor(data$groupname, levels = c(1,2,3), labels = c("group 1", "group 2", "group 3"))

Year <- matrix(1, N, 1) # data$year_0 <- 1
Year <- cbind(Year, ifelse(data$treated=="treated",rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4), rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4))) # data$year_1
for (i in 2:10) {
  lastcol <- Year[,ncol(Year)]
  Year <- cbind(Year,
                ifelse(data$treated=="treated", 
                       ifelse(lastcol==0,  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4)), 
                       ifelse(lastcol==0,  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4)))
                )
}
```

You can speed up a little bit with preallocation (but the big part is the sampling):

```
set.seed(1234)
K <- 10 # year_0 ... year_K
Year <- matrix(NA, N, K+1)
Year[,1] <- 1  # year_0
Year[,2] <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4), rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4)) # data$year_1
for (i in 3:(K+1)) Year[,i] <- ifelse(data$treated=="treated", 
                                      ifelse(Year[,i-1]==0,  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.035/4)), 
                                      ifelse(Year[,i-1]==0,  0, rbinom(N, 1, 1-0.05/4)))
```

If you want you can put the dataframe and the matrix `Year` together. If so, better assign columnames to the matrix:

```
colnames(Year) <- paste0("year_", 0:K)
```